# Nest API access for Time-to-Temperature, Optimized Start, Optimized Stop and Thermostat level Away

Tags: nest-api

I'm using the Nest API to monitor an install with 5 Nest Thermostats.

Having reviewed the Nest docs I seem unable to access the following data - is there anyway to access it via the official API?

- Time to temperature - the time the Nest thinks it will take to reach target temp
- Optimized Start (Mode) - the nest is pre heating before a desired setpoint as its learnt how long a room takes to heat
- Optimized Stop (Mode) - the nest has stopped calling for heat as it knows the room will retain heat until the next set point
- Away/Home per thermostat - the API only seems to provide Away information at the structure (home) level but I'm specifically interested in the occupation level at a per thermostat basis e.g. is someone in that room

All feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are not currently part of the API.